# Doctrine repository hints in PhpStorm

Tags: php, dependency-injection, doctrine, phpstorm, type-hinting

This is a two part question.

**First**, I can't seem to find out how to make PhpStorm correctly hint Doctrine repositories:

Entity looks like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="UserRepository")
 * @Entity @Table(name="users")
 */
class User
{
```

Repository looks like this:

```
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class UserRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getUser() {}
}
```

But when access the repository methods like so:

```
$userRepository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
$user = $userRepository->getU... // getUser() is not suggested
```

PhpStorm doesn't suggest the `getUser()` method.

The only workaround I found is:

```
/** @var UserRepository $userRepository */
$userRepository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
```

But this seems to be a bit bothersome to do it every time I need some repository.

Also, **second** part of the question is that I can't use repository as class property:

```
private EntityManager $em;
    
private UserRepository $userRepository;
    
public function __construct(EntityManager $em) {
    $this->em = $em;
    $this->userRepository = $em->getRepository(User::class);
}
```

Because it says:

```
Incompatible types: Expected property of type '\MyProject\UserRepository', '\Doctrine\Persistence\ObjectRepository|\MyProject\User|string' provided
```

How to set this up correctly for both cases?

Comment: Have you installed and enabled the Symfony plugin for PHPStorm?

Comment: Thanks, this solved the first problem. By any chance, do you have any idea how to solve the second problem?

Comment: Does the `UserRepository` exist in your project? How did you create the entity? If you're getting started with Symfony it might be a good option to use the [maker bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SymfonyMakerBundle/index.html) and `make:entity` command. I've been using Symfony for years and that's still my preferred way - it autogenerated the code using the latest conventions.

Comment: Ok this is strange, I could swear I had PHP type errors with the second problem, not just in PHPstorm, but now it works. I don't get it. Anyway, PHPStorm also suggests entity methods (like getId(), getName() etc. on repository. Can I make it to suggest only repository methods (findOne(), etc and custom repository methods?)

Comment: It sounds like it has the wrong type hint for the repository somewhere, you could try clearing the cache, clearing PHPStorm cache and restarting and seeing.

Comment: Consider that the return type for `EntityManager::getRepository` is `EntityRepository|ObjectRepository` (which might slightly differ depending on your Doctrine version). Both of which are supertypes of your `UserRepository` and do not implement `UserRepository::getUser`. PHPStorm can't derive the subtype of your repository this way without help. Luckily Doctrine adds [psalm](https://psalm.dev/) annotations to help it do so. That said, why not inject `UserRepository` directly instead of asking the entity manager for it (which is bad practice)?

Comment: Jeroen I experimented with it too. I even read a nice article from Tomas Votruba about it. But I don't want add basic repository methods (findOne(), etc) to every repository every time.